# Recover Drupal website after being hacked

Tags: security, drupal, drupal-7

I am a web developer for a lab; the other day our website got hacked.  The hacker left an index page with his own message.  So my employer shut down the server.

After I got back and turned the server on, the previous version of the website was up (have no idea how).  My employer wants me to bring back the most recent version of the website.  The previous programmer used Drupal to create the site.
Also all the files, folders and data from the most recent website still exist.  The only thing that changed is how the website looks.

I am new to Drupal so I do not know if there is any way for me to revert the layout back to its original form.  If not, what are my best options (rebuilding it from scratch will take too long).

Thanks,

Comment: try to import your theme, files and DB into a fresh Drupal installation. You should check the DB for existence of suspicious code like "base64". Google "Drupalgeddon"

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to do some necessary checks to remove any hacked files.

1. Create a copy of your website (files and database) to a local (or test machine).
2. Install [drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush) (on the same machine). Check the docs if you have never heard about the Drupal shell!
3. Install drush extension [drupalgeddon](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalgeddon) on the same machine running this (drush) command: `drush dl drupalgeddon`.
4. Install module [site_audit](https://www.drupal.org/project/site_audit) running this command: `drush dl site_audit && drush en -y site_audit`
5. Clear drush caches running this command: `drush cc drush`.
6. Run the test for Drupalgeddon and other "hacking" problems running this command: `drush asec`. 
   You will see a lot of useful information on the console.
7. Optional, install modules [security_review](https://www.drupal.org/project/security_review), [hacked](https://www.drupal.org/project/hacked) for additional security checks.

You can find more details about all these to the specific modules pages. Probably you will have to **[update Drupal core](https://www.drupal.org/node/1494290)** to the latest version in any case and then look at the reports for additional issues.

If you **database** is affected too you have to do a lot of work to do and this is not a job for a new user to Drupal.